# How to pair letters with multiples of 10 in python (0A-9A then 0B....)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will ID items in a list by giving them a number from 0-9 followed by a letter. It works like this: the first 10 items would be 0A, 1A, 2A all the way to 9A. Then I want to 11th item to be 0B. Is there anyway to have python do this automatically? I'll put an example of a list of products that need an ID for question purposes.

```
import random
import string

alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWYZ"
products_fruit = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes"]
fruit_id = range(0, len(products_fruit))

for id, product in zip(fruit_id, products_fruit):
  print("0" + str(id) + str(alphabet[0]) + " =", product)
```

You can see that right now I'm just printing an A but I want my 11th item to automatically have str(alphabet[1]) (the letter B) printed after to be 0B.
The outcome for this code is:

```
00A = apple
01A = banana
02A = orange
03A = grapes
```

I want the 11th and 21st product to be:
    00B = product11
    00C = product21

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWYZ"
products_fruit = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grapes"]

for idx, product in enumerate(products_fruit):
    if idx >= len(alphabet) * 10:
        raise ValueError("products_fruit contains too many entries")

    ch = alphabet[idx // 10]
    no = idx % 10
    print('0', str(no), ch, ' = ', product, sep='')
```

Comment: Thank you. I just added the product after the ID. I appreciat it

Comment: Ohh thank you. lol so what if I wanted an AA to come up after 9Z instead of that error?

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to do this is `itertools.product`, which works as a "multi-for loop" of sorts.

```py
import itertools
import string

for letter, number in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, range(10)):
    print(f"{number}{letter}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the for loop like this:

```
for id, product in zip(fruit_id, products_fruit):
  print("0" + str(id%10) + str(alphabet[id//10]) + " =", product)
```